# Parametrized type alias for Bifunctors

Tags: scala, functor, scalaz, type-alias, bifunctor

I have a `Seq[R]` and I wanna split this into a `Tuple2[Seq[E], Seq[S]]`, while I was coding this I thought about the fact that I could use a custom `Bifunctor` for a tuple of seqs and as exercise tried to code this:

```
import scalaz.Bifunctor

type MyType[E, S] = (Seq[E], Seq[S])

case class MyVali[E, S](tp: (Seq[E], Seq[S]))(implicit bifunctor: Bifunctor[MyType]) {
  def bimap[C, D](f: (E) => C, g: (S) => D): (Seq[C], Seq[D]) =
    bifunctor.bimap(tp)(f, g)

  def leftMap[C](f: (E) => C): (Seq[C], Seq[S]) =
    bifunctor.leftMap(tp)(f)

  def rightMap[D](g: (S) => D): (Seq[E], Seq[D]) =
    bifunctor.rightMap(tp)(g)

}

val myValBifunctorInstance = new Bifunctor[MyType] {
  override def bimap[A, B, C, D](fab: (Seq[A], Seq[B]))(f: (A) => C, g: (B) => D): (Seq[C], Seq[D]) =
    (fab._1.map(f), fab._2.map(g))
}

MyVali((Seq.empty[String], Seq.empty[Int]))(myValBifunctorInstance).bimap(a => a, b => b)
```

This works fine but for some reason obscure to me I had to declare a parametrized type alias to make all this compile, namely `type MyType[E, S] = (Seq[E], Seq[S])` and I hardly understand why this works while this doesn't:

```
def myValBimap[E, S] = new Bifunctor[Tuple2[Seq[E], Seq[S]]] {
  override def bimap[A, B, C, D](fab: (A, B))(f: (A) => C, g: (B) => D): (C, D) = ???
}
```

> [error] ... (Seq[E], Seq[S]) takes no type parameters, expected: two
>
> [error]   def myValBimap[E, S] = new Bifunctor[Tuple2[Seq[E], Seq[S]]] {

Is the compiler creating a 2-type suspension (like a nested lambda type maybe?) when such a type alias is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def myValBimap[E, S] = new Bifunctor[Tuple2[Seq[E], Seq[S]]] {  ... }
```

The `Tuple2[...]` in the `Bifunctor` above doesn't have two type parameters anymore because the `E` and `S` are filled in.

Eg `myValBimap[Int, String]` tries to create a `Bifunctor[(Seq[Int], Seq[String])]` and the type `(Seq[Int], Seq[String])` clearly has no two type parameters.

You could write

- `Bifunctor[({ type λ[α, β] = (Seq[α], Seq[β])})#λ]` or
- `Bifunctor[λ[(α, β) => (Seq[α], Seq[β])]]` using the kind projector plugin.

You need an implicit function with a type parameter if you need an additional type, maybe something like :

```
implicit def myBimap[F[_]: Functor]: Bifunctor[λ[(α, β) => (F[α], F[β])]] = ???
```

A simpler example is the `Functor` for disjunction / `\/` which uses a type parameter for the left side :

```
implicit def functorDisj[L]: Functor[L \/ ?] = ???
implicit def functorDisj[L]: Functor[({ type λ[α] = L \/ α })#λ] = ???
```

---

About your original problem: It might be possible to map your `R` to `E \/ S` and use `separate` :

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val integers = List.range(1,10)
val stringOrInts: List[String \/ Int] = 
  integers.map(i => if (i % 2 == 0) i.right else i.toString.left)

stringOrInts.separate
// (List[String], List[Int]) = (List(1, 3, 5, 7, 9),List(2, 4, 6, 8))
```